# How to generate a sequential unique id in a thread-safe way

Tags: c#, multithreading

i have called multiple threads which generates a number but i wanted to generate a unique no with all threads,( suppose one thread generates a no ie ABC1 but second thread must generate ABC2 and so on)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: To clarify, are you just looking to increment a counter in thread-safe fashion?

Answer (score 9):

You could use `Interlocked.Increment`, which will complete a thread safe increment on the counter.

```
public class Person
{
    private static int _counter;

    public string GetNewId()
    {
        int id = Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);
        return $"ABC{id}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I second your answer. `Interlocked.Increament` is relatively faster than implementing a `lock`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a thread safe way to generate unique numbers, then you can do something like this:

```
private static object _lock = new object();
private static int mIdx = 0;
public static string GenerateNumber()
{
     lock (_lock)
     {
          return $"ABC{mIdx++}";
     }
}
```